# When do we need to create our own custom dependency property?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am pretty much new to Silverlight and hence after going through a dozen of articles on dependency properties I am still a bit confused about when do we need to explicitly create our own custom dependency properties? Those technical terms on those articles have confused me a lot. Can anyone explain me the scenario that when do we need to create our own DP when suppose using a **textbox** . 
If it is at all for binding only we could easily bind the text to something else in Viewmodel but why do we need a DP to be created on our own?
I am bit confused. Please help me with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb: You should never need to create any `DependencyProperties` in your ViewModels.

Explanation:
You are using `Controls` to compose your View from, those Controls need to have DependencyProperties because their values are filled through `DataBindings` (a DataBinding would not be functioning when the corresponding property is no DP). But the source for that value does not need to be a DP (even if it is TwoWay binding). So your ViewModel can have ordinary Properties.

So only when you are at a point where you create your own custom Controls you will also need to define DependencyProperties inside these controls, otherwise you cannot use DataBinding.

Comment: Besides data binding, you would need to create a dependency property if you want to animate it or set its value in a Style Setter, or you wanted to have an explicit default value, to which the property can be reverted at any time. On the other hand it is not necessary to have a dependency property in a control when you only want to be able to set its value in XAML (without data binding etc). An ordinary CLR property would then be sufficient.

Comment: Can you please explain with an example ? For a textbox when do we need to create a DP of our own ?

Comment: There is no need to create a dependency property when you just want to *use* a TextBox. It would only be necessary in derived controls that declare additional properties.

Answer (score -1):

As a rule of thumb, use them only on controls for properties you want to set or bind from xaml.
There's a great overview here on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358(v=vs.110).aspx#backing_with_dp